# DynamicObject.TryConvert not called when casting to interface type

Tags: c#, dynamic

The following code throws an exception. TryConvert is not being called for the cast to interface. Why is this? Can I work around the problem?

```
using System.Dynamic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            dynamic test = new JsonNull();
            var ok = (string)test;
            // Next line throws:
            // Unable to cast object of type 'ConsoleApplication1.JsonNull' to type 'ConsoleApplication1.IFoo'.
            var fail = (IFoo)test;
        }
    }

    class JsonNull : DynamicObject
    {
        public override bool TryConvert(ConvertBinder binder, out object result)
        {
            result = null;
            return !binder.Type.IsValueType;
        }
    }

    interface IFoo { }
}
```

Comment: What does the documentation say? Is this supported?

Comment: Did you ever find out a way to get around this?

Answer (score 13):

I've found that if you change this line:

```
var fail = (IFoo)test;
```

to this:

```
IFoo success = test;
```

it works as expected.

It seems that only an implicit conversion works in this case. Looks like a bug to me.

I also find it very annoying that this fails as well:

```
class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    dynamic test = new JsonNull();
    Fails(test);
  }
  static void Fails(IFoo ifoo) { }
}
// ...
```

Because it looks like it should use an implicit conversion too. Another bug?

Comment: It also works for return values: `IEnumerable SomeFunc() { dynamic x = ...; return x; }` calls TryConvert on my dynamic object

Answer (score 9):

I suspect it's because in C# (and possibly .NET in general) you can't create a user-defined conversion to an interface type (in the same way that you can't create a user-defined conversion to/from a base/child type). Every interface conversion is therefore treated as a box or a reference conversion.

That really *is* just a guess though.

EDIT: On the other hand, I've just had a look at the code generated for:

```
dynamic d = ...;
IDisposable x = (IDisposable) d;
```

and it *does* generate a dynamic call via `Binder.Convert`, so it's not the C# compiler doing this. Hmm.

Comment: That was my hunch too. I assume casting to an interface is not meant to return a different object instance, just a different view of the same instance.

Comment: @Andrew: You might want to *try* implementing `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` yourself. I wonder whether it gets that far.

Answer (score 7):

This behavior is explained in the blog post [On Dynamic Objects and DynamicObject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/2010/10/18/on-dynamic-objects-and-dynamicobject.aspx) by Chris Burrows:

> "There is another snag in DynamicObject (..) when the call site’s underlying language provides some binding for any operation, that binding overrules any dynamic bindings that might exist.
>
> (..) recall that there is always an explicit conversion from most class types to any interface type in C# (6.2.4, bullet 3), though they can fail. (..)
>
> Just to expand on the interface conversion example a bit, it’s especially weird since if the conversion were implicit (say, try assigning to a local), then the dynamic conversion would have worked. Why? Because the C# binder would have said, “nope! no implicit conversion to IEnumerable,” and then the DynamicObject implementation would have let TryConvert do its thing."